# Finding all matches of string, and also returning line number of match

Tags: php

I have a string variable which contains some text (shown below).  The text has line breaks in it as shown.  I would like to search the text for a given string, and return the number of matches per line number.  For instance, searching for "keyword" would return 1 match on line 3 and 2 matches on line 5.

I have tried using strstr(). It does a good job finding the first match, and giving me the remaining text, so I can do it again and again until there are no matches.  Problem is I do not know how to determine which line number the match occurred on.

```
Hello,
This is some text.
And a keyword.
Some more text.
Another keyword! And another keyword.
Goodby.
```

Comment: Try to explode on the newline and loop through the lines. That's the best thing I can think of right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not split the text on line-feeds and loop, use the index + 1 as a line number:

```
$txtParts = explode("\n",$txt);
for ($i=0, $length = count($txtParts);$i<$length;$i++)
{
    $tmp = strstr($txtParts[$i],'keyword');
    if ($tmp)
    {
        echo 'Line '.($i +1).': '.$tmp;
    }
}
```

Tested, and working. Just a quick tip, since you're looking for matches in a text (sentences, upper- and lower-case etc...) perhaps `stristr` (case-insensitive) would be better?
An example with `foreach` and `stristr`:

```
$txtParts = explode("\n",$txt);
foreach ($txtParts as $number => $line)
{
    $tmp = stristr($line,'keyword');
    if ($tmp)
    {
        echo 'Line '.($number + 1).': '.$tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach maybe? might be a bit more clean. Also, you're using a function at the loop call.. that way the function will be called every single time it loops. You should pre-define that for maximum performance :)

Comment: @Rune, I thought about assigning the length while I was typing this code. Edited my answer accordingly. Either way, I tested this, and output was a nice `Line 3: keyword. Line 5: keyword! And another keyword.`, which I think is what the OP is after... nips! I thought I had written `foreach`, I've been writing a lot of JS lately, force of habit I guess

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can have all data in one array (Linenumber and position numbers)

```
<?php
$string = "Hello,
This is some text.
And a keyword.
Some more text.
Another keyword! And another keyword.
Goodby.";

$expl = explode("\n", $string);

$linenumber = 1; // first linenumber
$allpos = array();
foreach ($expl as $str) {

    $i = 0;
    $toFind = "keyword";
    $start = 0;
    while($pos = strpos($str, $toFind, $start)) {
        //echo $toFind. " " . $pos;
        $start = $pos+1;
        $allpos[$linenumber][$i] = $pos;
        $i++; 
    }
    $linenumber++; // linenumber goes one up
}


foreach ($allpos as $linenumber => $position) {
    echo "Linenumber: " . $linenumber . "<br/>";

    foreach ($position as $pos) {
        echo "On position: " .$pos . "<br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angelo's answer definitely provides more functionality and is probably the best answer, but the following is simple and seems to work.  I will continue to play with all solutions.

```
function findMatches($text,$phrase)
{
    $list=array();
    $lines=explode("\n", $text);
    foreach($lines AS $line_number=>$line)
    {
        str_replace($phrase,$phrase,$line,$count);
        if($count)
        {
            $list[]='Found '.$count.' match(s) on line '.($line_number+1);
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Why use `str_replace` to count the occurrences? `substr_count($line,$phrase);` will do just fine

Comment: Thanks Elias, I agree substr_count() is better